# In GNOME 3, how does one assign keyboard shortcuts for applications besides the default applications?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

In GNOME 3, there's a facility to assign keyboard shortcuts for applications like your default browser, default email client, default terminal etc. How do I do this for other applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no GUI application allowing that for gnome 3. If you have Gnome 2, you can still use the settings application from menu.

The easiest ways for me is to edit settings through **gconf-editor**:

1. specify your command in
   /apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/command_X
2. specify your keyboard shortcut in
       /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/run_command_X

The name of keyboard you can find using **xev**. X stands for number from 1 up to 12.

Comment: In Gnome 3, `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts`; afaik, it has always been there.

Answer (score 4):

To assign hotkeys without limitations like '12 user defined hotkeys' try [xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys)

Answer (score 3):

As said in a comment that should be an answer by [don_cristi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti):

> In Gnome 3, System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts;
>   afaik, it has always been there.

Comment: It does not allow some keystroke (ex: Shift+enter)

Comment: In GNOME 3.30, it's Settings > Devices > Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts, and then scroll down to the bottom and click the + button to add a custom shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

In GNOME 3 press <kbd>Meta</kbd> and start typing `shortcuts`. Alternatively go to `Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard`.

Then at the bottom press `+`.

[image]